# Is it possible to combine two attribute value with one xpath query?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Sample xml

```
<Resources>
    <Resource>
        <UID>14</UID>
        <Name>Entertainment</Name>
        <ID>2</ID>
    </Resource>
    <Resource>
        <UID>12</UID>
        <Name>Movie</Name>
        <ID>1</ID>
    </Resource>
</Resources>
```

Expected Output:

```
14,Entertainment
12,Movie
```

Comment: With XPath queries it's a good idea to specify your XPath version. We tend to assume 1.0 if not otherwise specified, partly because if you had XPath 2.0+ this would be so easy that you wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: I am using Micro focus operations orchestration tool which I believe have xpath 1.0 version.

Answer (score 2):

In XQuery:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '&#10;';

/Resources/Resource/string-join((UID, Name), ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done on a single Xpath 1.0 expression

```
concat(concat(//Resource[1]/UID/text(), ",", //Resource[1]/Name/text()), " ", concat(//Resource[2]/UID/text(), ",", //Resource[2]/Name/text()))
```

Which is of the form

```
 concat(concat(elem1, "," elem2), " ",concat(elem3, "," elem4))
```

Testing on command line

```
 xmllint --xpath 'concat(concat(//Resource[1]/UID/text(), ",", //Resource[1]/Name/text()), " ", concat(//Resource[2]/UID/text(), ",", //Resource[2]/Name/text()))' tmp.xml ; echo
```

Result:

```
14,Entertainment 12,Movie
```

Comment: But of course this only works if there are exactly 2 Resource elements in your input. For the general case where the number of Resource elements is unpredictable, I don't think it can be done in XPath 1.0 - it needs XPath 2.0 (or XQuery)

Comment: Yeah. I just shared example of the xml format. The element number is not standard. Sometimes we get 200 elements and sometimes 500. Is there a easy way to query x number of elements?

Comment: There's no way in XPath 1.0 to concatenate a variable number of strings into a single string.

Comment: How can we achieve using xquery? Can this be done in sql?